# Find PHP application external calls

Tags: php

Let's say I have a Monolithic and huge codebase project written in PHP in a localhost

Is there some service that can report on runtime all the external calls made? Some code may be using php directly or using curl instead.

Maybe the right approach is not a php application to do this, but some kind of daemon that can give you that information from the operating system. I am using Mac OS X.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the  *Observer Pattern*, classes already exist in the SPL classes `\SplObserver` and `\SplSubject`.
When you have a very big project, you surely have abstracted most of it and have wrappers for curl calls and database etc (if not, you should consider going for according design patterns!).

```
class YourCurlWrapper implements \SplSubject {
    public function setObservers($observers) {
        $this->observers = $observers;
        return $this;
    }
    //notify observers(or some of them)
    public function notify() {
        foreach ($this->observers as $value) {
            $value->update($this);
        }
    }
}
```

See the classes `SplObserver` and `SplSubject`.

http://php.net/manual/de/class.splobserver.php

If an external call is an outgoing network connection, you can use `ngrep` or `tcpdump` to collect the outgoing or **incoming traffic**.

A third possibility, probably the easiest and fastest, is to setup a proxy (like squid). You can see all URLs called in its logfiles and you don't have to change any PHP code. Just your environment needs to know the proxy:

```
http_proxy http://localhost:3218
https_proxy http://localhost:3218
ftp_proxy http://localhost:3218
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clear, this is legacy code inherited from another team. Doing changes on the code is not possible. What I need is something like this: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/applications-menu/monitoring/external-services-dashboard

Comment: @MauricioLopez I have added another possibility. I don't think relic works without implementing one of the above things. That would be magic. Programing is logic, not magic D: